# How to encrypt in python using a key (*.key file) generated by Microsoft Enterprise Library (Security.Cryptography)?

Tags: python, .net, encryption, cryptography

I am totally newbie in cryptography so my problem is probably trivial but I'm hitting a wall...

The short version: 
In database, I have hashed and encrypted password by EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.
In python, I want to read the key generated by Enterprise Library and encrypt password again (plain text) and next compere hashes.

More details:
As I said, database stores hashed passwords. 
Passwords are encrypted and hashed using Microsoft Enterprise Library (Security.Cryptography).
Here are more details about configuration:

> **Symmetric Crypto Providers**: algorithmType="System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged name="AES"
>
> **Hash Provider**s: algorithmType="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed
>   saltEnabled="true"  name="SHA256"

The key is generated by importing a password-protected key file in **Cryptographic Key Wizard** provided by **EnterpriseLibrary**. [More info in part 'To import a password-protected key file'](https://documentation.help/MS-Enterprise-Library-5.0/EntLib50_c1e33058-145c-47fb-a7cd-158e0b1468c5.html)

So now I have that *.key file and want to use it in python to encrypt and hash plain text and compare it with hashed password in database.

How use that key? I tried a lot of libraries (cryptography.fernet, pycrypto, crypto) but always facing problem to use/open the key. 
Even in text editor it looks strange (combinations of @@)

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Microsoft is terribly bad in describing which algorithms are actually used, especially when it comes to key storage. Maybe you can include a test key encoded in hexadecimals or base 64?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes so the information from <securityCryptographyConfiguration> is not enough?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'encoded in base64'? Should I first convert it before use it? And why it looks so strange in a text editor? A mix of random characters